# Restart an app if it is force quit

Tags: automation, applications

I have the [Freedom](http://freedom.to/) app installed to control my procrastination.

However, I can force quit Freedom from the Activity Monitor, and the remainder of the week just goes by without me getting anything done.

Is there any way by which I can restart this app if it is quit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is! [launchd.info's cookbook](http://www.launchd.info/) has an example to keep Safari open. We can amend that to suit your, uh, *anti-procrastination needs*. Amending the original (Safari) version results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.freedom.keepAlive</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
            <string>-W</string>
            <string>/Applications/Freedom.app</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Save that as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.freedom.keepAlive.plist`. Check the last `<string>...` line - is that where `Freedom` is on your Mac? Edit the file if necessary and re-save it. Then use `launchctl` to load your anti-procrastination launch agent into `launchd`:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.freedom.keepAlive.plist
```

Check your launch agent is running with:

```
launchctl list | grep freedom
```

And finally - try quitting `Freedom`. If all goes well your attempt to procrastinate should be thwarted.